# Locked in a User Account

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, multi-user, xposed-framework

My device (maybe) doesn't support Multiple Users.  I have a rooted device with Xposed Framework installed.

I installed an app from the Play Store (I think it's named as "Multi Users", or other similar to that ...), grant that app a root access, and enable that feature.  Then, I go to "Settings", and the "Users" Option was there.  I add another account, and when it opened a Dialog Box telling me to setup that account now, I rebooted my phone because it was too slow ...

Now, when the phone had finished rebooting, my apps are gone (I mean, when I try to open them, they keep telling me `Application not installed`);  as well as my third party launchers, lockers, clocks, etc.

Previously, I had done this before (but with a different app), and it gives me options on the Lock Screen to switch to Users.  But, this app doesn't have that option.

Also, the "Users" options is now hidden / not displayed on the Settings.

I also downloaded the ".apk" file of Root Browser (I already downloaded ES File Explorer, but cannot launch it due to that "Application not installed"), but it won't let me install either.

Will [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) fix this?  - *I hope so ...*

My device is running Samsung Galaxy Core Prime - Android 4.4 (Kitkat) with Root and Xposed Framework installed.

**Please HELP!**

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible things:

- Hold the power button. Some phone has "Switch User" option on power menu.
- Hold the "Power Off" option and select "Reboot to safe mode". May be you can figure out something from safe mode.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help me.  There is no "Switch User" option on the Power Menu.  And, I still cannot switch users when I'm on to Safe Mode.  Anyways, thank you for providing answers! 

Comment: @LloydDominic but while in safe-mode you could remove that app, which hopefully lets you access your other apps again.

Comment: By the way, it was hard on recognizing the app that did that thing, because the Application Manager (on Settings) displays the Package Name of the App, not the name of the App itself.

Comment: I uninstalled the app, and it still doesn't let me change accounts, etc.  The app just activates the feature, so when I uninstall the app, nothing happens.  Right now, I'm hoping an `ADB` solution.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm so lucky, I just tested it, and it worked!*

So, the `USER_ID` for the Primary User Account is `0`.

---

Using your favorite Root - Only File Manager, navigate to `/data/system/users`, delete the other User Accounts ...

For example,
the "unknown" `USER_ID` is 10,
delete these files / folders:

- Folder named `10`.
- `10.xml`
- `10.xml.mbak`
- And, edit the userlist.xml removing these line:

  - `<user id="10" />`
- And if you want, you can also delete that line from `userlist.xml.mbak`.

  - *(I think nothing will happen if you delete that file, because I think this is only a backup)*

---

If your stock File Manager doesn't let you access the root drive / system files, follow these steps:

- You may have to download an `.apk` of the Root File Manager that you want to use, using another device.
- Push the downloaded `.apk` file to `/system/app` on your Android Device using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).
- Reboot the device.
- The `.apk` should now be installed automatically, and you are ready to do the steps above.

---

**Bonus tip**: You should also delete other files / folders, if you want to only use the Primary Account.